# Woher kommt das Negative in "Zustände"

Tags: etymology

Es gibt in Deutsch zwei Wendungen in denen Zustände per se negativ ist.

> Zustände sind das hier.
>
> Da kriegt man ja Zustände.

Seit wann gibt es die, und woher kommt die Negativität?

Comment: Was meinst Du mit "negativ"? Dass man die Zustände geändert haben möchte? Die Frage ist, ob das so absolut zutrifft, oder nicht eine übersimplifizierung darstellt, also ob nicht Situationen denkbar sind, in denen man Zustände vorzufinden oder zu verspüren begrüßt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Ursprünge reichen ins 17. Jahrhundert zurück. Grimms Wörterbuch vermerkt dazu unter [Zustand, (siehe 5.)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ12054):

> "... 5) das wort z. hat eine besondere gefühlsbetonung angenommen, von der
>   eine neuerdings üblicher gewordene bedeutung ausgegangen ist: das
>   einer, wer den z. mit ansieht, sich des weinens unmöglich enthalten
>   kann Chr. Reuter Schlampampens krankheit 119 ndr.; was war das
>   vor ein z. auf der see Schelmuffsky (vollst.) 48 ndr.; ist es nicht
>   ein z.? im neuen jahr ... sitzest du im wirthshaus! Abr. a s. Clara
>   etwas für alle 2 (1711), 110;
>
> welch ein zustand!herr, so späte schleichst du heut aus deiner kammer
>   Göthe 6, 213 W. so ist in der umgangssprache der unwillig entrüstete
>   ausruf zustand üblich geworden, auch nd. tostand! ..."

D.h. [Chr. Reuter](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Reuter_%28Schriftsteller%29) bemerkte eine "neuerdings üblich gewordene" Bedeutung dieser Art zu seinen Lebzeiten.

Über den Grund kann man nur mutmaßen: Das Normale, also der (Normal-)Zustand an sich, ist oft nicht erwähnenswert. Wird dagegen ein Zustand benannt, ist er deswegen vermutlich nicht in Ordnung.

Answer (score 0):

Im ersten Fall "Zustände sind das hier" fehlt offensichtlich der Vergleich, weil solche Vergleiche nur zu gut bekannt sind.
Im zweiten Fall ist das Negative oder der Vergleich auch nicht ausgesprochen, aber man versteht was gemeint ist, "Zustände wie kurz vor dem Herzinfarkt" oder "zum Haareausraufen" oder so was Ähnliches.

Comment: Das weiß ich, aber seit wann ist das so? Und wurde der Vergleich mal ausgesprochen?

Answer (score -4):

A simple explanation without reference would be:

> One *Zustand* = Order.
>   Multiple *Zustände* = Chaos.
>
> Order = Good
>   Chaos = Bad

*Zustände* literally means that things are out of control; nobody has any clue what's going on = chaos.

If you get *Zustände*, that means you are no longer your "normal" self but are forced to go into a different mode of operation which is usually some kind of emotion like anger, agitation, embarrassment etc.

But since you – as a German – are used to remain in control of yourself instead of getting *Zustände*, you are just talking about what you would get (*Zustände*) instead of actually getting them. Then you will calmly and efficiently bring order into the chaos and be the hero in shining armour. Or you'll just leave and write an angry letter.

Comment: [A good German](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Good%20German)? [See also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good_German). I'll remove "good" for now ;) – What is "camly"? I guess "calmly", I'll update that.